# Can a rule be declared in a define in gnu-make?

Tags: gnu-make

I thought that I could use the `define` directive in make to make multiple alike rules

```
define TESTPRG

${1}: 
        echo Build ${1}

endef

$(call TESTPRG,x)
```

But I get this output

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'echo', needed by '
x'.  Stop.
```

It looks like the newline in my define is lost

```
$ make -n -p | grep echo
make: *** No rule to make target 'echo', needed by '
x'.  Stop.
    echo Build ${1}
x: echo Build x
echo:
```

Am I just trying to do something that the `define` is not supposed to be used for.

Kjeld

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what `define` is supposed to be used for. You just need to remember to `$(eval)` it as a part of Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
define TESTPRG

${1}:
        echo Build ${1}

endef

$(eval $(call TESTPRG,x))

$ make
echo Build x
Build x
```